# How many arrangements are possible for forming a group of 3 students, if each group should consist at least 2 students majoring in Mathematics?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose a class consists of $4$ students majoring in Mathematics, $4$ students majoring in Islamic Studies and $5$ students majoring in Computer Science. How many arrangements are possible for forming a group of $3$ students, if each group should consist of at least $2$ students majoring in Mathematics?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The question could be worded more clearly.   To rephrase, in how many ways can a group of three students be selected if it contains at least two students majoring in mathematics?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: In addition to the other criticisms: are students with the same major **distinguishable** from each other?  For example, suppose that Person-1 and Person-2 are both majoring in Islamic Studies.  Also, suppose that Group-1 contains Person-1 but not Person-2.  Suppose further that Group-2 is identical to Group-1, except for the sole difference that Person-2 has replaced Person-1.  **Is it your intent** that Group-2 be considered the same as or different than Group-1?